# Comparing Values on the Same Row

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry if this has been answered but hours of Google-ing has revealed no elegant solution.

I have a sheet that looks like this only there are hundreds of rows.

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+
| A | B | C | D |  E  |
+---+---+---+---+-----+
| X | a | Y | b | 1.2 |
| X | b | Y | c | 1.5 |
| Y | c | Z | c | 1.8 |
+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

My goal is to count rows where for example the character in column A="X", character in column C="X" and characters in columns B and D are not the same (B!=D). The first part is working...

```
COUNTIFS(A:A ,"X" , C:C, "X")
```

but I can't figure out how to compare two cells that are both part of a range but on the same line. The following seems to compare the whole ranges...

```
COUNTIFS(A:A ,"X" , C:C, "X", B:B, D:D)
```

Additionally, I'd like to sum the values in column E for similarly defined groups.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Added the following formula to each row in column F...

```
=(B:B=D:D)+0
```

That will return 1 or 0 depending on whether the contents of B and D is matching. And that is something I can add to my existing formula.

```
UNTIFS(A:A ,"X" , C:C, "X", F:F, 0)
```